# Mongo Bulkwrite with $addToSet

Tags: mongodb

I have been trying a bulkwrite but get complained about typing (I think it's about the syntax):

```
        Type '{ roles: string; }' is not assignable to type 'SetFields<any>'.
          Type '{ roles: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NotAcceptedFields<any, readonly any[]>'.
            Property 'roles' is incompatible with index signature.
              Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

I can't find any examples or docs about using $addToSet in a builkwrite. Here it is (INTER_ADMINS is just an array of string):

```
const bulkUpdates = INTER_ADMINS.map((ethAddress) => {
    return {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { ethAddress },
        update: {
          $addToSet: {
            roles: 'INTERNAL_ADMIN',
          },
        },
        upsert: true,
      },
    };
  });

  
  const res = await db.collection('users').bulkWrite(bulkUpdates);
```

users collection sample:

```
{
   ethAddress: 'something',
   roles: ['role1','role2']
}
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct, this is just a `typescript` error. I recommend you just add a `@ts-ignore` and move on.

Here is the type definition:

```
export type UpdateQuery<TSchema> = {
    ....
    $addToSet?: SetFields<TSchema> | undefined;
    ....
};
```

```
export type SetFields<TSchema> = ({
    readonly [key in KeysOfAType<TSchema, ReadonlyArray<any> | undefined>]?:
        | UpdateOptionalId<Unpacked<TSchema[key]>>
        | AddToSetOperators<Array<UpdateOptionalId<Unpacked<TSchema[key]>>>>;
} &
    NotAcceptedFields<TSchema, ReadonlyArray<any> | undefined>) & {
    readonly [key: string]: AddToSetOperators<any> | any;
};
```

As you can see because the Schema is not provided typescript doesn't know which are the valid "keys" of the schema so the only valid type left in the `SetFields` is the `NotAcceptedFields` fields type (which are `null` and `undefined`, not `string` )

If you provide a Schema to the operations I believe it should sort the issue:

```
const bulkUpdates: BulkWriteOperation<UserSchema>[]  = ...
```